# Prove that for closed $A$, continuous mapping $f(A)$ is not necessarily closed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity

Suppose $A \subset \textbf{R}^n$ is closed, and $f: A \rightarrow \textbf{R}$ is continuous. How to prove that $f(A)$ is not necessarily closed?

I wanted to prove this by showing $f(A)$ is not necessarily compact, but don't know how to proceed. Do I need to show that not every sequence in $f(A)$ has a converging subsequence?

Comment: Showing that $f(A)$ is not compact is not a way of showing that it is not closed, for a set may well be closed and not compact.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the subset $A\subset\mathbb R^2$ of all points $(x,y)$ in the plane such that $xy=1$, and the function $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ which projects on the first coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

To prove a "not necessarily" statement, all you need is a counterexample. Lots of counterexamples can be given to refute this claim. Here's one.

Let $n=1$, $A=\mathbb{R}$, and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined via $f(x)=\arctan x$. Then $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is continuous, but $f(A)=\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.